# lexicalized parser vs dependency parser

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am new to NLP concepts , i am little bit confused with the concepts of lexicalized parser and dependency parser. Are they the same thing or if not in what ways they differ.
kindly help to understand. I am using Stanford parser java package.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lexicalized parsing aims at building a tree structure from a set of tokens. So a correctly parsed sentence could for example return two sub phrases, so the **syntactical** structure of the sentence is identified.

Dependency parsing however, aims at finding relations between the words. For example, consider the sentence "I have never ever seen this before". A dependency parser could find a (directed) auxiliary relation from "have" to "seen". So a dependency parsing indicates the **(grammatical)** relations between

This is a rather informal explanation but maybe you can make some use of it.